# How can i make my script center img in div

Tags: javascript, css

I have concocted a little script here out of bits and pieces I have found and scraped together, but I need a little help to add an extra function to it,

### First of all - this is what it is doing for me at the moment:

- It resizes and crops/letterboxes an image to completely fill a div
  which is a % height and a % width – it keeps doing this whenever and
  whatever window resize
- It keeps working seamlessly as the window is resized
- The image is filling 100% the area the div covers - left to right
  and top to bottom.
- The image is not being squashed or stretched - just being cropped
  or is overflowing.
- The image is kept as small as possible, so whatever the resize -
  you can still see either the very sides OR the very top and bottom of
  the image.
- It seems to be OK across IE9, Fire Fox, Oprea, Chrome, and Safari
  over XP and 7

All of these things are very important to me, please don't tell me that all i need is:

```
<img style="width : 100%;">
```

This is so much more than that. It's not too easy to explain but check the demo and drag the corner of the window around and that'll be worth 1000 words...!

### Now, what I want to add:

All it is, I’d like the letter box to centre on the image.

When the div is a very tall portrait or a very flat landscape I’m just getting the top or just the left hand side of the image.

I’d like the centre of the original image to stay in the centre of the resized div.

I’ve tried a few things but have drawn a blank. I’m sure the script could feed a minus top: or left: into the style but it seems if I get too many div’s in div’s IE doesn’t like it, or what am I doing wrong?

Thing is I don’t really know how to wright this stuff, I only steal bit and bobs and splat them together…

### And finally [the demo](http://generationsinc.co.uk/test/Copy%20%282%29%20of%20java.html)

### And the script:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>


<style>

#imgarea {
position:absolute;
right:0px;
height:75%;
width:70%;
top:25%;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

function resizeImage()
{
    var window_height = document.body.clientHeight
    var window_width  = document.body.clientWidth
    var image_width   = document.images[0].width
    var image_height  = document.images[0].height
    var area_width    = window_width * 0.7
    var area_height   = window_height * 0.75
    var height_ratio  = image_height / area_height
    var width_ratio   = image_width / area_width


    if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
    {
        document.images[0].style.width  = "100%"
        document.images[0].style.height = "auto"

    }
    else
    {
        document.images[0].style.width  = "auto"
        document.images[0].style.height = "100%"

    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body onresize="resizeImage()">
    <div id="imgarea">  
<img onload="resizeImage()" src="f/a.jpg">  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks Very Much For This.

Comment: you should really learn this stuff instead of stealing bits and bobs...

Comment: thankyou Ninja, i know, i know...  all i can say is i'm learning fast - which is hopefully the point :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quiet sure if that's what you're looking for, but let's try this:
*upd: the wysiwyg is not working on comments at this moment, so sorry for messy code snippets.

1.Position the div#imgarea relatively. You can then float it to the right, to replicate your right:0px declaration. Don't forget to hide the overflow, to ensure that 'letter-boxed' parts of the image stay hidden.

```
#imgarea {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    height: 75%;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden; 
     top: 25%;
};
```

1. Some user agents will add paddings and margins to the body element, thus preventing the image container to slide all the way to the right. Reset those, to get rid of the gaps between the container and the edge of the browser window.

   body {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }
2. As for the image itself, position it absolutely.

   img {
       position: absolute;
   }
3. And finally javascript. To center the image, you need to calculate what this width/height=auto sums up to, and then reset left/top attributes respectively. Your if function needs to be adjusted just a bit; leave your variables as is:

```js
if (height_ratio > width_ratio) {
    var newWidth, newHeight, newTop;
    newWidth = area_width;
    newHeight = image_height/width_ratio;
    newTop = -(newHeight-area_height)/2;
    document.images[0].style.width  = newWidth;
    document.images[0].style.height = newHeight;
    document.images[0].style.top = newTop;
    document.images[0].style.left = 0;
}else{
    var newWidth, newHeight, newLeft;
    newHeight = area_height;
    newWidth = image_width/height_ratio;
    newLeft = -(width-area_width)/2;
    document.images[0].style.width  = newWidth;
    document.images[0].style.height = newHeight;
    document.images[0].style.top = 0;
    document.images[0].style.left = newLeft;
}
```

I hope that if this doesn't solve the issue completely, it at least sends you in the right direction. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work exactly, but may get your started. I had a client request a radial gradient be fixed to the left and right of a website's main ontent section. The page was set up with dynamic widths and I had a heck of a time getting one solid image to work, so I came up with a quick css solution.

```
#bgHold #gradLeft{
    width:248px;
    height:975px;
    position:fixed;
    right:50%;
    margin-right:399px;
    background:url("../images/gradLeft.png") top center no-repeat;
}
```

margin-right is half of the content block's width. So basically, the gradient is fixed on the page at 50% from the right, then shoved left 50% of the content box making it line up with the edge of the content. The same idea applies to the other side.

Now, with your situation, perhaps you can set `right:50%;` and `margin-right:`imgWidth/2?